# Aligning Images In HTML

Tags: html, css, image

I'm working on a website for my HTML class and have come come across a slight issue. I am using the  tag to divide my page up into several sections, with each section having a different class. If at all possible, I'd like to have the images I'm including within the boxes being created to the right of the lists.

Here is what I have so far, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Halo Multiplayer Maps By Title</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="my_halo_style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Halo Multiplayer Maps by Title</h1>
    <p>
    There are so many different maps across the many Halo titles that it can even be difficult for the most devoted fans to keep track of which maps appear on each game.
    Below, I have compiled a list of each Halo title with its corresponding maps. 
    </p>
    <h2>Take Note:</h2>
    <p>
    Several of the later titles had numerous other multiplayer maps added through different map packs. 
    These extra maps are not included in the list below, but can be found by clicking the links to each title's informatino page.
    <img src="halo.jpg" title="Halo Logo" alt="Halo Logo" align="middle">
    </p>

    <div id="halo1">
    <h1>Halo:Combat Evolved</h1>
    <p>
    <ul>
        <li>Battle Creek</li>
        <li>Blood Gulch</li>
        <li>Boarding Action</li>
        <li>Chill Out</li>
        <li>Chiron TL-34</li>
        <li>Damnation</li>
        <li>Derelict</li>
        <li>Hang 'em High</li>
        <li>Longest</li>
        <li>Prisoner</li>
        <li>Rat Race</li>   
        <li>Sidewinder</li>
        <li>Wizard</li>
    </ul>
    <img src="Halo_Combat_Evolved.jpg" title="Halo:Combat Evolved" alt="Halo:Combat Evolved Cover" align="right" />
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Don't know that it's actually needed, but here is the external style sheet I'm using for my class designs.

```
body 
            {
            background-color: black;
            color: blue;
            text-align: left;
            margin-left: 15%;
            margin-right: 15%;
            border: 10px double blue;
            padding: 20px 25px 20px 25px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            }

#halo1 {background-color: black;
    color: green; 
    border: 5px outset green;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 50px;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: left; }

 #halo2 {background-color: red;
    color: orange;
    border: 5px outset orange;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 50px; 
    width: 400px;
    text-align: left; }

#halo3 {background-color: orange;
    color: black;
    border: 5px outset black
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: left; }

#halowars {background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        border: 5px outset white;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 50px;
        width: 400px;
        text-align: left; }

#haloreach {background-color: black;
        color: silver;
        border: 5px outset silver;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 50px;
        width: 400px;
        text-align: left; } 

#halo1a {background-color: silver;
            color: black;
            border: 5px outset black;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 50px;
            width: 400px;
            text-align: left; }

#halo4 {background-color: black;
        color: blue;
        border: 5px outset blue;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 50px; 
        width: 400px;
        text-align: left; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give a line break for your image to start on a new line and on the right.
The following code will update ALL images in this web page to align to the right.

```
img {
float: right;
clear: both;
display: block;
}

#halo1 {background-color: black;
color: green; 
border: 5px outset green;
padding: 10px;
margin: 50px;
width: 600px;
text-align: left;
height: auto;
float: left; /* so it will wrap the images */
}
```

For your HTML, you could update to the following:

```
<p>
Several of the later titles had numerous other multiplayer maps added through different map packs. 
These extra maps are not included in the list below, but can be found by clicking the links to each title's informatino page. 
<br><img src="halo.jpg" title="Halo Logo" alt="Halo Logo" align="middle">
</p>
```

[Dabblet demo here.](http://dabblet.com/gist/9799916)

Comment: Thanks, but that's still not really giving me what I'm envisioning. See, the final page will have one box per halo title and each box will have a list of the multiplayer maps for that game. I have images of each game case that I want to include inside the boxes for each game.

Comment: Do you have a diagram? I'm not really good at visualizing what you need :(

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I also noticed that in the original post I said I wanted the images to the left of the lists, but I meant to the right.

Comment: It would be similar to the demo you included in your answer, but there would be an image within the borders of the Halo:Combat Evolved box to the right of the list of maps. I don't know if that clears it up any.

Comment: I updated the Dabblet demo. Do take a look and see if that is what you want? In this case instead of floating left, the CSS will input float: right so the images will float to the right.

Comment: That's extremely close. Is there a way to get the image in the upper part of the box rather than at the bottom?

Comment: Yes, you will need to move your images to the top. Updated demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/9800103

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your image with `<p>` tag and align it with `p.yourClass{text-align: center;}`.